# Android HttpClient Exception Control issue (Manager is shut down)

Tags: android, exception, httpclient

My app posts some strings to my server.
It use HttpClient to send datas.
All functions are perfect without 1 problem..

If My phone is on networking state then
I click submit button -> Datas can be send on my server. (real very well)

If My phone is unnetworking(disconneing) state (it means not using wifi or 3g...)
I click submit button -> It showing up Error Dialog as 'You have to check network'

But Problem is...
**As soon as(about in 0.5~1.5 seconds)** I click wifi enable button then I click submit button, 
The HttpClient post execution showing up exception problem.(FC)
Can I control the exception problem?
I want showing up error dialog but, The exception, I can't control.
I think during wifi is enabling (or 3g), the execution something happen problems.

***This is error sentence***

02-06 00:48:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(20183): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.

***The Source***

```
(...ready for setting params, and string datas..and so on)

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);
                httpPost.addHeader("cookie", cookie);

                //↓This execute is problem. How can I control exception?
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = resEntity.getContent();
                return content;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problematic line is

```
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

[This is the original Apache documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e646), without more code (and the full stack trace) is difficult to understand what's going on. I think it's just bad API usage