# HTTP Illegal state exception

Tags: android, http, android-json

I have the following code, which in general works without problems:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(sendURL);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( postJSON.toString(), "UTF-8");  
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);
response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

When postJSON has the following, I get an IllegalStateException, with the message "Manager is shut down":

```
{"action":"add","items":["61515"],"screen":"display","customer_number":"200001013"}
```

I got a similar message when the items array had malformed content, but I don't see the problem here.  Also, the response is immediate, so I am pretty sure that the HTTP library is throwing the exception, not the server.  What is wrong with this JSON object?

Furthermore, testing the JSON at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) shows me that the JSON parses correctly, including the array with "61515", which is the new element in the code.

Comment: i think "items":["61515"] is the problem.

Comment: it should like "items":[{"61515"}]

Comment: @Aharon Manne pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9151098/1396082